# How to store an image in an IBM DB2 Database using python?

Tags: database, db2, blob, azure-blob-storage

I can connect to my IBM DB2 database using a python file, I can run all sorts of commands through it, but how do i store an image to a column in my table on DB2 database? I have create A BLOB TYPE COLUMN in my table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not look at the test cases for ibm_db on github?

They show a test case for using the `PARAM_FILE` option to `ibm_db.bind_param()`  to cause the contents of an image file to be copied into a `BLOB` column .

See the testcase [here][1].

Although the test(s) may be out of date, the following snippet of code
shows the parameters that work using ibm_db version 3.0.1 (successfully insert a jpg file into a BLOB column) via the PARAM_FILE method:

```
jpg_file="/home/some_user/Pictures/houston.jpg"  # path to the image file

# table my_pics already exists with a blob colum called jpg_content of appropriate length
# The database already contains a table called MY_PICS in the current schema
# with a BLOB column named JPG_CONTENT
#

insert_sql = "INSERT INTO my_pics(jpg_content) values(?)"
try:
    stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn, insert_sql)
    print("Successfully prepared the insert statement")
except:
    print("Failed to compile the insert statement")
    print(ibm_db.stmt_errormsg(stmt))
    ibm_db.close(conn)
    sys.exit(1)

# link a file-name to the parameter-marker of the insert-statement (target column is BLOB)

try:
    rc = ibm_db.bind_param(stmt, 1, jpg_file, ibm_db.PARAM_FILE,ibm_db.SQL_BLOB )
    print("Bind returned: "+str(rc))
    print("Successfully bound the filename to the parmameter-marker")

except:
    print("Bind returned: "+str(rc))
    print("Failed to bind the input parameter file")
    print(ibm_db.stmt_errormsg(stmt))
    ibm_db.close(conn)
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    ibm_db.execute(stmt)
    print("Successfully inserted jpg file into blob column")
except:
    print("Failed to execute the insert to blob column")
    print(ibm_db.stmt_errormsg(stmt))
```